# Narrow type of T[K] when using K extends keyof T, while also making a property optional based on the type of T[K]

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define an interface with 2 properties:

1. The *key* of a generic type (T)
2. And given the type of that key's value, a function that accepts arguments of only that type (i.e. T[K])

And:

1. It should ensure that *property 2* is made optional when T[K] is a string or number.

---

In my case, this interface takes the shape of a configuration object for sorting tables.

```
interface BaseColumnSortProps<T extends object, K extends keyof T> {
  sortField: K;
  sort?: (a: T[K], b: T[K]) => number;
}

type ColumnSortProps<T extends object, K extends keyof T> =
  T[K] extends string | number ?
    BaseColumnSortProps<T, K> :               // don't require "sort" for strings and numbers
    Required<BaseColumnSortProps<T, K>>;      // require custom "sort" for all other types
```

And ColumnData contains the sort configuration:

```
interface ColumnData<T extends object> {
  sort?: ColumnSortProps<T, keyof T>;
}
```

Given this interface, I should be able to define the following function:

```
function testFunction<T extends object>(config: ColumnData<T>[]) {}
```

And where T contains only strings and number, `sort` should be optional:

```
interface OnlyStringsAndNumbers {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

testFunction<OnlyStringsAndNumbers>([
  { sort: { sortField: "a" } },                         // is optional, works ok (no errors)
  { sort: { sortField: "b", sort: (a, b) => a - b } }   // but the types for "a" and "b" are a union of all possible types for T[K]
])
```

And where T has custom/unhandled types, `sort` should be required on those keys only:

```
interface OtherTypes {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

testFunction<OtherTypes>([
  { sort: { sortField: "a" }},    // fails to allow "sort" method to be optional
  { sort: { sortField: "b" }},
  { sort: { sortField: "c" }}
])
```

Here is a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUHsCcBdQJIDtYFNoDMCGBjVAofASxXWz1ACEsBnVAYUgBsBXAWySjgAVpIAHGgB4AKqFQAPNEgAmNUJABGAK1Q5YAGlABpcVNSz5Aa1QBPSBlAiAfKADe%20UKBoxYAMSKomMgFw6A3I7OrgD8fgAUWH4iANraALpaitFx8QCUoAC8tkjsiuiBAL6EsKb8qKCMrBxcsLwCwmKS0nIKKmqaOnotxmYWVraZQbEJ3QatNLDQJADmoAA%20oLls%20dCgIUFO1HRV7Jyu9YKiWtq2fk4Xl1cgoDKQSADk8NCoAI4sRC%20gAEQucN%20gDAwZxTWbyLCyJZ5dA0TagABKbw%20LxkQm2DGYe1qh0aJ2s1n8V1ANxe70%20FRwLEmkDYPz%20sABQLWWCYTAUsAAFuhQKVyrDiKRMLgKrsOAARLCwLCiMaGNqqdS2BxOelhSqYmoHPhHERaEzmSw2IqEfAYFhIdREe481CTNzmy33GXNcbyJQK2DWcI4e4YIgzPyipASqWiawxdL2Yr4G7INBCigAdyInIUSCYphB0yQM3BkOWq35JHj5AqAHl06ZwKCczQAIKyABy0Og8mVoCiWdmgScyShKwK%20GjaDtDtgVqQQgrGer2dzDZkzYHra9MSCdmCcD8G-pHi8vh%20WABhVAhS0RIvl4uN0TMCMbqMoHCSEg4mgfFbaXXm9g25-e%208PxvkUb4tHpCIsCSDJsg7UAAFpQEUU9kKcG5FBYeBOQqXlbUBYFviPDtIWAgEsC%20LBQHNCcFEsFk2X4SAaBoIhFCYbCylwpkrFSfB0kIWNBVLUBk1TSAsLWHCi0E4VQDLcSRA4tsgk7SY5x7RC-ALQcnBwPxFEgZhUAhY18BHdwxwnKd5MU1dv3A%20x-08QDD2PM9LhubAiCYeRYFfOjIETOlXABNhUE5SAZB5V98gUfhx3uFk7NcP9dycg8SNPM8kq3BzUv3ICcFc3iv0IIA) of what I currently have.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8gPVW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, your approach works a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, the `sort` property of `ColumnData<T>` needs to treat each property of `T` individually.  You don't want `ColumnSortProps<T, keyof T>`, because that mixes all of the properties together at once.  Instead what you'd like to do is *distribute* `ColumnSortProps<T, K>` over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `K`.  `ColumnSortProps<T, K>` doesn't do that automatically.

One way to do that is with a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of the form

```
type DistribColumnSortProps<T extends object, K> =
  K extends keyof T ? ColumnSortProps<T, K> : never

interface ColumnData<T extends object> {
  sort?: DistribColumnSortProps<T, keyof T>
}
```

but that turns out to be tricky to write inline:

```
interface ColumnData2<T extends object> {
  sort?: keyof T extends infer K ? (
    K extends keyof T ? ColumnSortProps<T, K> : never
  ) : never
}
```

Another approach because `keyof T` is keylike is to write a *distributive object type* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where we [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `keyof T` and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with `keyof T`, to get a union:

```
interface ColumnData<T extends object> {
  sort?: { [K in keyof T]: ColumnSortProps<T, K> }[keyof T];
}
```

---

All three of those approaches result in the desired behavior:

```
testFunction<OnlyStringsAndNumbers>([
  { sort: { sortField: "a" } },
  { sort: { sortField: "b", sort: (a, b) => a - b } } // okay
])

testFunction<OtherTypes>([
  { sort: { sortField: "a" } },  // okay
  { sort: { sortField: "b" } },  // okay
  { sort: { sortField: "c" } }   // error, 
  //~~~~
  // Property 'sort' is missing in type '{ sortField: "c"; }' 
  // but required in type 'Required<BaseColumnSortProps<OtherTypes, "c">>'
])
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-rAb5IEItF4QxhHEaxMgcaJXHWOEMRBDutLbsEcAeF4vjfFg-yFIhGi6YZsAGbSxneH4XyKF8Wj6aAkRJBk2S8aAAC0oCKIhIXXJARhYKY+DpIQyGpnOGFYWyrIcms-IUfFNHsugIhlJ+9hBHxYZEYJQWDpxpU4H4iiQMwqDgg+ElftJsnydl0C5TyWk6U4emuPZriOaZXzmSFhRaISYDhZFNkeX1RmeE53yuWNE1hRFUW9bZA0LSZzk4BZIVONc6B8NAWhBCAAB+N1XZdYAHOgpSgPctL3FW8hsMKNCzPuXJ5S983uItw0HfihTvfdQUsE8CKkjIf38i98IkkiKK0GiXbnjG1HtZ1n5aF8B24vc0VpFaQA)